# SFML GetRenderWindow Method Help

Tags: c++, sfml

I have been following the "SFML Game Development By Example" and on chapter 2, the book was showing the example game design of a *Snake* game. However he didn't write the code of some header classes and didn't mention whether they should exist. I tried writing some of them but encountered an error:

```
sf::RenderWindow* Window::GetRenderWindow(return &m_window;)
```

Error: declaration is incompatible with `sf::RenderWindow *Window::GetRenderWindow()`

In my Window class:

```
class Window{

public:
    ...
    sf::RenderWindow* GetRenderWindow();
    ...
private:
    ...
    sf::RenderWindow m_window;
    ...
}
```

I think it is probably because of the function declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for the silly question. It is time to sleep I guess. Here is the corrected version:

```
sf::RenderWindow* Window::GetRenderWindow() {
    return &m_window;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to come back and mark this answer as accepted when it's possible :)